# GDAL GetGeoTransform Documentation -- Is there an oversight, or what am I misunderstanding?

Tags: gdal, documentation

The [documentation](https://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#a5101119705f5fa2bc1344ab26f66fd1d) for GDALDataset::GetGeoTransform says some things that are rather confusing.

> Fetches the coefficients for transforming between pixel/line (P,L) raster space, and projection coordinates (Xp,Yp) space.
>
> ```
> Xp = padfTransform[0] + P*padfTransform[1] + L*padfTransform[2];
> Yp = padfTransform[3] + P*padfTransform[4] + L*padfTransform[5];
> ```
>
> In a north up image, `padfTransform[1]` is the pixel width, and `padfTransform[5]` is the pixel height.
>
> The upper left corner of the upper left pixel is at position (`padfTransform[0]`,`padfTransform[3]`).
>
> The default transform is `(0,1,0,0,0,1)` and should be returned even when a CE_Failure error is returned, such as for formats that don't support transformation to projection coordinates.

If this is a matrix, it makes sense that Pixel_X is at 1,1 and Pixel_Y is at 2,2.

Here is my question:

So should the equation for Yp be:

```
Yp = padfTransform[3] + L*padfTransform[4] + P*padfTransform[5];
```

in which the positions of L and P are swapped?

Or if I am confused about something, can someone help me get unconfused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

For a north up image with no rotation (i.e. `padfTransform[4] == padfTransform[2] == 0`), the formula simply becomes:

```
Xp = padfTransform[0] + P*padfTransform[1];
Yp = padfTransform[3] + L*padfTransform[5];

# Where P = column number and L = row number
```

i.e add the starting X (or Y) to the column (or row) number multiplied by the pixel width (or height).

The rotation terms may be what's tripping you up...?  When a pixel is rotated, the `Y` skew needs to be considered when calculating the `X` map coordinate and the `X` skew needs to be considered when calculating the `Y` map coordinate.  There's a quite  detailed explanation in the [wikipedia article on world files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file).

Comment: That there is rotation is what was tripping me up. So can you tell me what P and L stand for? I naively supposed that P was Pixel dimension and L was Line dimension (the lines between pixels). Yes, that is as foolish as a sophomore reasoning with senior. In that vein, what do those letters stand for?

Comment: @philologon P is column number, and L is row number. These are "coordinates" on the raster image.

Comment: Thanks. I now see it is right there in the documentation. I always find a way to embarrass myself in these kinds of things, usually by skimming too fast.